# Parent Object not reactive when deleting Child Array object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have children and spouse data array in employee array. Whenever I delete children array the employee data is not reactive.

Comment: How do you delete it ? Provide some code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @kissu [link](https://prnt.sc/10gb0nn) Please see it. It is deleted in dev tools but reactive in component this.employeeData .

Comment: Please do paste actual code written in *text* in your question rather than hosting some code image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8816585

Comment: Please read this one wisely: [ask]. And then, edit your **question** to include **ALL** the updated and required minimal informations for us to help you. Then, your question will be valid. Otherwise, it will be closed pretty soon. Also, people here are helping you on their free time, so please make some effort for them.

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084, reading and respecting the site rules (and improving the quality of your question) shows us you care about getting useful answers. Obviously, investing the time into it is entirely your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **this.$set** property to make it reactive. Please look into advanced vue js reactivity concepts.